# Hoja de estilos css no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola tengo un problema con la hoja de estilos css que teniendo boostrap los cambios que pongo en la hoja de css no hace nada.

```html
<head>
  <title>Pruebas Javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="funciones.js"></script>
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="estilos.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

  <div align="center">
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      Escribe tu <label>nombre </label> <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" required> <br><br> Escribe tus <label>apellidos </label> <input id="apellidos" type="text" name="apellidos" required><br><br> Escribe tu <label>edad </label><input id="edad"
        type="text" name="edad" required><br><br>
      <label>Sexo</label><br> Masculino <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino"> Femenino <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino"><br><br>

      <div name="aficiones">
        <input type="checkbox" name="aficion" value="1"> Tenis <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="aficion" value="2"> Futbol <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="aficion" value="3"> Baloncesto <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="aficion" value="4"> Motociclismo
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="boton" name="boton" value='Aceptar' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrar()">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola Rubén. Puedes explicar qué es lo que no te está funcionando ?

Comment: inspecciona la web con tu navegador (por ej, con chrome puedes usar ctrl+may+i) y mira si te da un error de carga del archivo, a ver si no te esta cogiendo el archivo estilos.css

Comment: Me esta cogiendo todos los estilos de boostrap. No coge nada de la hoja de estilos.

Comment: Prueba en tu hoja de estilos a añadir `!important` tras uno de ellos como el color de una fuente o algo así

Comment: He añadido el !important y no lo coge

Comment: html{
 background-color: red !important;
}

Comment: Como te han comentado si pulsas para ver el código fuente, si pulsas sobre el enlace para ver tu hoja de estilos, ¿la carga correctamente?

Comment: Si si que la carga, creo lo que pasa que algunas propiedades las pisa boostrap porque he cambiado el color de un h1 y si lo ha hecho. Asique sera boostrap.

Comment: Si, el problema es por el orden de la carga de hojas de estilos, yo siempre he tenido ese problema con bootsrap, pero poniendo `!important` para mi se arreglaba

Comment: Primero, asegurate de que estés importando bien las hojas de estilo (muéstranos la ruta de tu css).

Comment: He removido Stack Snippet porque se incluyen referencias relativas, entre ellas al archivo de hojas de estilo que es de lo que trata el problema, y Stack Snippet no puede cargar esos archivos. Por otro lado, falta agregar el código, de CSS y JavaScript. Véase [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Te digo lo que suelo hacer yo:

Bootstrap suele comerse los estilos propios, así que no intentes dar estilos a elementos html (`<h1><div>`...) ni a las propias clases de bootstrap, a no ser que quieras modificar todos los `<h1>` y darles otro estilo.
Para esto entra en tu hoja de estilos de bootstrap.css y edita la propiedad que modifica a los .

*(Viendo tu código, estás usando bootstrap desde bootstrapcdn.com - Descárgate bootstrap y súbelo a tu sitio para poder editarlo a tu gusto)*

Añade tus propias clases en el elemento a modificar y, si fuera necesario, métele el `!important` delante.

Todo esto **pruébalo antes en el editor de estilos del navegador** que utilices para saber qué propiedad de bootstrap está machacando la tuya.

Comment: El `!important` va detrás de la propiedad en cuestión, aún así, no es la mejor práctica para realizar un cambio de estilos.

Comment: Al utilizar Bootstrap te atañes a eso si no quieres modificar la base de bootstrap.css

Comment: No tiene por qué, realmente lo que hace bootstrap (y otros frameworks del estilo) es utilizar selectores combinados con una gran especificidad. Con una buena gestión de la [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) podrías modificar los estilos de un elemento concreto sin necesidad de utilizar `!important`. Por supuesto, esta última es mucho más rápida, pero también existe la posibilidad de "ganar" a los estilos de bootstrap sin necesidad de modificar el framework.

Comment: "Bootstrap suele comerse los estilos propios" Mis ojos!

Comment: Llevo trabajando muchos años en empresas pequeñas y ahora estoy en una internacional. Todas trabajan así. No se puede perder tanto tiempo en tener una perfecta gestión de la especifidad. Si trabajas de esto sabes que los segundos cuentan.

Gracias @Bitito por tu aportación. Te habré sacado uno dado que se te ha olvidado la primera exclamación.

Comment: A la larga da más problemas de los que soluciona. De todas formas que se haga así por falta de tiempo o interés en muchas empresa a no es excusa para que aconsejemos malas prácticas

Comment: @JordiHuertas: Aunque se esperan que las respuestas sean completas, es válido publicar respuestas parciales. Los comentarios se usan para criticar, solicitar que se aclare ya sea una pregunta o respuesta, explicar una edición, entre otras otras cosas. Las soluciones u orientaciones para resolver algo, deberían publicarse como respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, borré lo de que no tenías permiso para comentar, porque eso no justifica publicar un comentario como respuesta, pero en este caso se trata de una respuesta, no de un comentario en el sentido que se les da en la red de sitios de Stack Exchange.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @blonfu, que sea habitual no significa que sea lo correcto. Evidentemente el tiempo apremia, y es por eso que en muchas empresas se utilizan malas prácticas. A la larga puede generar muchos problemas de inconsistencia de estilos y estilos que es imposible de sobreescribir por este motivo. El abuso de `!important` no debería considerarse una buena práctica, lo cual no quiere decir que en muchas empresas lo utilicen así (para casos muy concretos yo también lo he tenido que utilizar).

Comment: Gracias @Rubén. Como es tan mala práctica dadle una solución mejor. A mí no me han dejado nunca donde he trabajado hacerlo de esa manera que proponéis aunque la conozco, al igual que no me dejan "perder" el tiempo en comentar código. Si conocéis alguna empresa de desarrollo que busque la eficiencia (que no la eficacia) avisadme que me mudo.

Comment: El `!important` forma parte del CSS y está por algo, hay veces que no queda más remedio que usarlo pero no conviene abusar como ha explicado @FranciscoRomero. No me puedo creer eso que dices de que no te dejan trabajar "así" porque la especificidad de los selectores no es una forma de trabajar sino una caracteristica de CSS, es como si me dijeras que no te dejan usar la letra "r" del teclado, no tendría ningún sentido

Comment: Creo que me he explicado mal o no me has entendido, @blonfu. Plantéate una empresa con 14 sitios web, 9 de ellos tiendas online mal optimizadas con llamadas a una media de 13 hojas de estilos y algunas con más de 50k líneas (estilos default de bootstrap, plugins... modificados y ampliados). No me dan tiempo para optimización y el important es mi mejor amigo. Dile a tu jefe que quieres cobrar por "organizar el taller" y no por "reparar coches", a ver qué te dice.

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente, llevo muchos años trabajando en esto, solo digo que no es buena práctica y al final con tanto `!mportant` tendrás que usar la especificidad igualmente pero añadiendo `!important` siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías darle relevancia o autoridad a tu hoja de estilo que quieres como "principal" colocando:

```html
<head>
  <title>Pruebas Javascript</title>
  (Primero la hoja con relevancia)<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="estilos.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="funciones.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>
```

O genera una hoja de estilo desde bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/